# Getting a new id for a firestore doc to add it to the document itself

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

According to the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document), it should be possible get an id for a not-yet-created firestore document, add it the object to be saved, and then persist it like this:

```
// Add a new document with a generated id.
var newCityRef = db.collection("cities").doc();

// later...
newCityRef.set(data);
```

In my application, I follow this pattern with the following code:

```
   async createNewProject(projectObject : Project) : Promise<boolean> {
      let doc =  this.firestore.collection("projects").doc();
      projectObject.id = doc.ref.id;
      try {
      await doc.set(projectObject);
      } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
        return false;
      }
      return true;
   }
```

When it runs though, i get an error in the console:

> FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined

Can anybody shed any light?  I've seen other folks on her referencing this method (using the doc method with no parameters as the solution to the problem, yet others are seeing this error.  Is this some kind of API on the Angular implementation of the API, or a problem at the firebase side of things (or did I do something wrong?)

Comment: Can you show how `this.firestore` is initialized?

Answer (score 0):

The [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) method returns a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference), which does not have a `ref` property but has an `id` one. Therefore you need to do:

```
projectObject.id = doc.id;
```

instead of

```
projectObject.id = doc.ref.id;
```

Comment: @user1023110 Hello, did you have the opportunity to look at the proposed answer?